# how to import ReactBootstrap to React

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

I'm trying to set up to work with node, express and React. So it all work out when I just serve my html file with some React script using res.sendFile() but when I tried to import ReactBoostrap it start to call error 'require is not defined'.
So I search google and find out I need to use something like webpack to fix it and I did. But now it just doesn't work like I import Button but it only show the plain button. So I just want to ask if someone could give me a guide on how to set up node, express with React and also how to import ReactBoostrap properly.

Comment: Show some code, which generates the *wrong* button, please only the `render()` method

Comment: import Button from 'react-bootstrap/lib/Button';
ReactDOM.render(
  <Button bsStyle='info'>s</Button>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);

Comment: maybe you did't include the css? check out my answer

Comment: yes, thank you. I forgot to include it when I include webpack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to include bootstrap css to the page.

Taken from the react-bootstrap docs:

> ### Stylesheets
>
> Because React-Bootstrap doesn't depend on a very precise version of
>   Bootstrap, we don't ship with any included css. However, some
>   stylesheet is required to use these components. How and which
>   bootstrap styles you include is up to you, but the simplest way is to
>   include the latest styles from the CDN.
>   `<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->`
>
> ```
> <link rel="stylesheet"href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/latest/css/bootstrap.min.css">
> ```
>
> `<!-- Optional theme -->`
>
> ```
> <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/latest/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
> ```
>
> For more advanced use cases you can also use a bundler like Webpack or
>   Browserify to include the css files for you as part of your build
>   process but that is beyond the scope of this guide. Also see
>   http://getbootstrap.com/customize/ for details about customizing
>   stylesheets to match your component use.

So, just put this line into the `<head>`

```
 <link rel="stylesheet"href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/latest/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```